# add custom tab to crm home page and not to entities in crm 2011

Tags: tabs, custom-controls, customization, dynamics-crm-2011

I have searched and saw only guides how to add tab to the home page and to all the entities or just to some specific entity like so : http://dynamicscrm2011.wordpress.com/tag/add-a-custom-button-to-custom-tab/

Any idea how to add custom tab just to my home page and not to appear in any other entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to add it to the Dashboard entity only then.

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/e9b407f4-2234-425b-9977-b0bae7f8e457

Comment: but then I will only see it in when I will be at the dashboard screen. I want to see it always near the "File" tab but only on the main screen of my website and I dont want to see it in any entity like account etc..

Comment: The dashboard is the default main screen.  If you only add it to Dashboards, then it won't show up for any other entity.